Can we create a dimension model without surrogate keys
My requirement is to create a dimension model using ELT techniques . My dimensions are dynamics and any data load issues will have domino effect on subsequent records and their surrogate keys. Is there a way dimension model with dimension tables in SCD Type 1 and SCD Type 2 and facts be built without surrogate keys ?
More of a research question in what do you think of this solution exists., what value does this bring to overall process ….

Hi - can you explain what you mean by “ My dimensions are dynamics” and why you would not want to use SKs?

The whole process of calculating surrogate key, mapping it to fact tables and then joining back the dimensions & facts to get the original dimensions back in reporting layer, I feel like the surrogate key are redundant.
Is there a way the surrogate keep be eliminated, what value does this bring to dw process wrt time money maintenance complexity etc.....

Hi - surrogate keys are a critical part of dimensional modelling and are in no way redundant. I suggest you start by reading Kimball’s book on Dimensional Modelling to understand why - and to understand why (and for what use cases) we use dimensional models in the first place

Surrogate keys are meaningless technical keys which has only significance to maintain one to one relationship between dimensions and facts. And they are tough to maintains and complex to build with integrity and neither scalable nor easy to migrate.

I understand Kimball's dimension model but just trying to take a step back and trying to reimagine a dw without surrogate keys... Is it worth to invest time in this kind of thought?

No, it isn’t - not unless you want to invent your own modelling technique to replace dimensional modelling
